# How to disable alerts for email in subfolders?

Tags: notifications, stock-email-app, alerts, email

The base Android email app on my honor 7 displays alerts for all mail regardless of folder. I don't want to see any of the high volume subfolders i have, just stuff sent straight to my top level inbox would be fine.

I'm sure this is a common use case. Get alerts about one-off top level mails, don't get anything for routine stuff that goes into subfolders. How to set it up?

Comment: try taking a look at the settings of your mail app, one might find such settings there.

Comment: @Enigma nothing more granular than turning all notifications on/off. There must be some email app out there that does this?

Comment: What mail app do you use ? @user1561108

Comment: As in question, the default android mail app in Honor 7. Willing to switch to whatever offers a solution though.